# Do specific operations on collection items

Tags: meteor

For my app I'm trying to set an operation on each item of a collection of Widgets. A widget Item contains an `url` (api rest), and a `period`. The goal is to loop through a widget collection and do something like this :

```
//Loop through collection

Meteor.setInterval(function(){
  Meteor.call('getData', <Collection>.url,function(e,r){
    if(e){
      console.error(e);
    }else{
      //Display the data into the template
    }
  });
},<Collection>.period);
```

In the template I'd like to do something like this :

```
{{#each widgets}}
    {{widgetItem}}
{{/each}}
```

I'd like to know what is the best way to do this ? I heard about Dynamics Templates with Telescope App but I don't know if it would be useful in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{{#each}}` [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md) magic changes the data context of the elements inside it.

Basically, assuming you have the following or a similar data structure for your widget:

```
{
  templateName : 'coolWidget1',
  templateData : { ... }
}
```

You could write something along the lines of:

```
{{#each Widgets}}
  {{> Template.dynamic template=templateName data=templateData}}
{{/each}}
```

Where `template=` and `data=` are the object parameters you pass to `Template.dynamic` (it will produce `{ template : templateName, data : templateData}`).
Then you can just pass `templateName` and `templateData` thanks to the `{{#each}}` changing the data context (Spacebars understand that you mean "the `templateName` and `templateData` of the current item of the loop).

So that was for the HTML. If you want to share the returned value from the `call` with the template, search for questions about `Session` or `ReactiveVar`, there's already a lot of stuff asked about it.